# What is Closed status of N1qlQueryResult couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm just getting status closed in in some intermittent `Select` query call to `Couchbase` in `N1qlQueryResult` object.

As per `Couchbase` documentation :

> Returns the final status of the query. For example, a successful query
>   will return "success" (which is equivalent to finalSuccess() returning
>   true).  Other statuses include (but are not limited to) "fatal" when
>   fatal errors 
>   occurred and "timeout" when the query timed out on the server side but
>   not yet on the client side. This method blocks until the query is over
>   and the status can be established.

The issue is coming when calling `query()` method:

```
public List<N1qlQueryRow> execute(String query, ScanConsistency scanConsistency) {
        final Bucket couchbaseBucket = getSampleCouchbaseBucket(); // get couchbase bucket here
        final N1qlQueryResult result = couchbaseBucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(query, N1qlParams.build().consistency(ScanConsistency.NOT_BOUNDED)));

        if (!SUCCESS.equals(result.status())) {
            throw new RuntimeException(//get errors here);
        }
        return result.allRows();
    }
```

I have now info about statuses [`success, timeout, fatal`]. But I'm wondering with status `closed` multiple times.  So my question is -

1. What are the statuses other than  [`success, timeout, fatal`] `Couchbase` returns in N1qlQueryResult.
2. What could be the possible causes for status Closed.

I'm using Couchbase 5.1 with Spring boot 1.5.9    .

Comment: Could you post an example of the code where this is occurring?

Comment: Could you post your logs?

Comment: @MatthewGroves  please check the sample code from which I'm getting error.

Comment: @MatthewGroves Also the status of N1qlQueryResult should be appropriate so that application can understand the possible root cause and customize.  Please change if possible.

Comment: @Saiprateek if you have a suggestion to improve the Java SDK, would you mind posting it to the Couchbase Forums here for the engineering team to see: https://forums.couchbase.com/c/java-sdk